# Access to a Service object through different Activities / Classes

Tags: android, object, service

I've got a `Service` which is playing music. It has different functions like 'play' ,'pause' , 'stop' etc. I'm creating the object for this `Service` in my `MainActivity` with `bindService()`. Everything works fine!

But how can I use this object through other classes (`BroadcastReceiver`, `Widget`) or another `Activity` while the `MainActivity` is not running ?

If I declare it static I only can access it when `MainActivity` is running.

How can I save/hold this `Service` object without it being deleted because the `Activity` finishes ?

Comment: you can call `bindService` in any Activity you want to talk to your `Service`

Comment: BUT "Only activities, services, and content providers can bind to a service—you cannot bind to a service from a broadcast receiver." , see section "Binding to a Service" at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html And a widget is a kind of broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use a bound service for media playback. Just use

```
 startService(myPlaybackIntent);
```

and before that supply the information the service needs (play/pause/skip/...) as an intent extra.

**EDIT**

If for example you use int constants like ACTION_PLAY = 0, ACTION_PREVIOUS = 1,..., then you can write

```
myPlaybackIntent.putExtra("your.package.name.MEDIA_ACTION", ACTION_PLAY);
```

before calling 'startService()' 
 and evaluate the intent extra at the beginning of the service's 'onStartCommand()' method:

```
if(intent.hasExtra("your.package.name.MEDIA_ACTION"))
{
    switch(intent.getIntExtra("your.package.name.MEDIA_ACTION", -1))
              // -1 = some value you don't use for your actions
    {
        case ACTION_PLAY: // start playback
        case ACTION_PREVIOUS: // jump to last song
        ...
    }

}
```

**End of EDIT**

There is a very nice [guide to media playback using a service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices) .

This way, you can keep your service from being stopped/deleted by returning with "START_STICKY" from the 'onStartCommand()' method in your service class.

The other good thing about using the 'onStartCommand()' method is that you can call it from a Widget. The only difference is that you first have to define a pending intent for each action you want to take.

Let's say your RemoteViews object (I assume you're familiar with widgets, if not - I learned a lot from [the guide at developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)) is called 'updateViews' and you have different integer constants for indicating which action to take, like 'ACTION_PLAY' for starting playback. Then for the 'play'-button (R.id.btn_play) you could write:

```
        Intent iPlay = new Intent(this, SVC.class);
        iPlay.putExtra("your.package.name.MEDIA_ACTION", ACTION_PLAY);

        PendingIntent piPlay = PendingIntent.getService(context, ACTION_PLAY,
                iPlay, 0);
        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_play, piPlay);
```

Please make sure to use different values for the second parameter of the 'getService()' method for the different pending intents you are going to need (play, pause, previous,...).

Because if you set up another intent like

```
Intent iPrevious = new Intent(this, SVC.class);
```

then - no matter what extras you put to iPrevious - if you code

```
PendingIntent piPrevious = PendingIntent.getService(context, ACTION_PREVIOUS,
                iPrevious, 0);
```

the system will know the difference between the pending intents only by comparing ACTION_PLAY to ACTION_PREVIOUS.

Comment: Cant I use both ? Because in my Service I did build up a object where all my music titles etc. are saved. And did I understand it right that I have to start a new Service for every controls with startService() ? Thank you very much you helped me to the right path !

Comment: @AhmetKazaman - Widgets can't bind to a service like activities (see my comment to your question). Having said that, you can use both ways of accessing the service in your application. If the service is already running, 'startService(myPlaybackIntent)' will not start another instance of the service. The intent will also be passed to the running service (for example if in my code example the user first clicked "play" and then clicked "previous"). So in the 'onStartCommand()' method, you can evaluate the intent extras and decide what to do. I added a code sample to my answer, hope this helps :)